# Input Box doesn't appear when macro is run from shortcut key

Tags: excel, inputbox, vba

I have a simple little Excel macro that opens a template, asks for a filename, and saves the file. It runs from the Microsoft VBA window without issues, but when the shortcut key is used from Excel, it opens the file, but doesn't show the input box.

```
Sub NewCommentSheet()
'
' NewCommentSheet Macro
' Opens the Comments and Recheck template. A dialog box asks for the data module name,
' which is then used for the filename of the new comment sheet.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+N
'
    'Opens the file

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Kelly.Keck\Documents\Projects\SBIR\QA Notes\Comments and Recheck Template.xlsx"

    'Defines variables. moduleName comes from the input box. newFileName uses moduleName _
    to create a filename: "Comments for [moduleName].xslx"

    Dim moduleName As String
    Dim newFileName As String

    'Asks the user for the data module name--default is set as the common portion of _
    the filename.

    moduleName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the name of the data module.", _
    Title:="Data Module Title", Default:="DMTitle-")

    'Checks to see if input was canceled. If canceled, ends the macro to avoid saving with an incorrect filename.

    If moduleName = "False" Then End

    'Saves file with the new name.

    newFileName = "Comments for " & moduleName & ".xslx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFileName

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it is a well known issue (I hope so). Let me post why this happens :)

Comment: BTW when I said "I hope so" I meant I hope lot of people are aware of that limitation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key in Excel is used to open a workbook to open the file without running macros and this interferes with running the rest of the macro.

**From [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555263) article**

> Excel is designed not to run Auto_Open and Workbook_Open code when a workbook is opened from the User interface whilst holding down the shift key. Unfortunately, this (desired) behaviour also applies when opening workbooks through VBA code.

**Resolution from the above link** (In case the link dies)

The workaround for this problem (only applicable on Windows ® platforms) is to detect whether the shift key is pressed and wait for it to be released before issuing the Workbooks.Open command:

```
'Declare API
Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Integer
Const SHIFT_KEY = 16

Function ShiftPressed() As Boolean
    'Returns True if shift key is pressed
    ShiftPressed = GetKeyState(SHIFT_KEY) < 0
End Function

Sub Demo()
    Do While ShiftPressed()
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Workbooks.Open = "C:\My Documents\ShiftKeyDemo.xls"
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I just experimented and the below seems to work. Adding `DoEvents` before the `Workbooks.Open`

```
Sub NewCommentSheet()
    Dim moduleName As String
    Dim newFileName As String

    DoEvents

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\book1.xlsx"

    moduleName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the name of the data module.", _
    Title:="Data Module Title", Default:="DMTitle-")

    If moduleName = "False" Then End

    'Saves file with the new name.

    newFileName = "Comments for " & moduleName & ".xslx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFileName
End Sub
```